# What do Outlook or OWA users see if a mailbox is moved while they are connected?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook, outlook-2010

What is the impact of moving a mailbox from Exchange 2010 to Exchange2010 (same forest same site) during business hours, while the user is connected?

What is shown in Outlook or OWA? (Does version matter?)

Will they have to reauthenticate

Comment: Moved from where to where?

Comment: @ewwhite Same forest, same site: E2010 in both directions.

Comment: Does it matter? The mailbox will be unavailable to the user during the move, and they will certainly be aware that they can't access their mail regardless of the actual message displayed by OWA or Outlook. If you want to move mailboxes during business hours, be certain you notify all the users their mailbox may become unavailable at some point during the day.

Comment: @August - It matters because I have time and operational constraints.  `"The mailbox will be unavailable during the move"` appears to be incorrect, since I did a test move and was able to log in using OWA.  Your statement was true for Exchange 2003 and earlier, but in E2010 that might not me the complete case.

Comment: @makerofthings7 - you are correct. I was thinking Exchange 2003 > 2010, but the experience differs based on Exchange version with the later versions having much reduced unavailability from the client's perspective. Provided a link in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I will simply refer you to this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298174%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx#ClientExp

Microsoft has detailed the client experience for various clients and Exchange versions.